# how to search for string inside chrome internal pages, using python and\or selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write script, that would allow me to search for a string inside Chrome's internal pages (for example: "chrome://help").
is there a simple way to do it, or does it require special tools, (like the Selenium webdriver API)?
i know it's possible to use it for "normal" web pages, but what about "internal" ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selenium Webdriver to easily achieve this task, and in this case we will extract the version number of Google Chrome.

Here is the sample code with comments explaining every step:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# executable path should be the place where chrome driver is on the computer

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/users/user/Downloads/Chromedriver')

# This line tells the driver to go to the help section of chrome

driver.get('chrome://help')

# Because certain elements are stored in another Iframe, you must switch to this particular Iframe which is called 'help' in this case.

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('help'))

# retrive the text of the element and store it's text in a variable.

version_string = driver.find_element_by_id('version-container').text

# Now you can easily print it.

print version_string
```